# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for supporting jar using hibernate & spring

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jboss

We have a web based project which uses some other dependent projects named "auth". This is the place where we do all authentication stuff.Our web based project uses hot deploy & whenever we changes anything under this any part which uses this "auth" starts giving

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/****/***/common/auth/entity/Application at $Proxy1596.findApplicationObjectByName(Unknown Source) at
```

This gets resolved when we restart our jboss all instance.   Is there any way to fix this NoClassDefFound error without restarting the server & affecting live traffic because of this?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss has some hot deploy issues when you load JARs that are external to your Spring application - when I work locally I experience the same thing.  Instead of trying to fix JBoss or Spring behavior, you could cluster your JBoss instances behind a front-end webserver, such as Apache, and roll your deploy, restarting your JBoss instances one after the other.  That way, users who might have been on the affected server will be bounced over to a happy one and your live traffic is maintained.